# Running laravel 4 and 5 together?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-4, laravel-5

We have our site running on Laravel 4.2 and have been thinking about upgrading to 5.0 for a long time now.

We also have a subdomain that we started building and decided to use Laravel 5.1 so that we could get used to it before the migration. We have the sub domain setup and installed and it is running.

However, our login  does not persist between the two domains. We have the domain set in session settings on both systems. The cookie gets set but I am assuming Laravel 4.2 and 5.1 have different auth systems therefore the cookie from 4.2 does not work in 5.1 and vice versa. We have also tried database sessions and file sessions without much luck.

1. Is there a way to convert a Laravel 4 session into a Laravel 5 session so that users can go from our 4.2 main site to our 5.1 sub domain easily?
2. Is it possible to make both types of cookie one for the 4.2 and one for the 5.1 at the same time so that users would have and use both domains?
3. Or are we looking at this all wrong and should try something totally different to get what we want?

Answer (score 1):

> Or are we looking at this all wrong and should try something totally different to get what we want?

Do you really need to run 4.2 & 5.1?

Personally I've done a few upgrades from 4.2 to 5.1 (and even 4.2 to 5.3 recently). Your best bet is just dedicate 3-4 hours (or even 1-2 days depending on the size of your app) and follow the upgrade guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

If you follow each step systematically - it is a fairly easy upgrade path.

Then put the 5.1 application in a sub-domain and have some users "test" the new version, before you push it into production.

There is also the Laravel Shift paid option as well: https://laravelshift.com/

Answer (score 0):

Watchout, Laravel 5.1 use a new Hash system, watch the line

```
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

in config/app.php and compare with the old app.php